# Mobile Device Quarantine Issue

Tags: exchange-2013, mobile-devices

We recently setup mobile device quarantine on our Exchange 2013 server and we saw an issue this morning when a user updated their AD password and then updated their phone with the latest information. When they did this their phone went into quarantine on our Exchange server, blocking them from reading their email.

They are using Outlook for iOS and Android 1.0 on their phone, any ideas as to why this would happen? I've done some searching on Microsoft's site and can't find a reason for this happening on a password change.

Comment: Is this a question or a statement?

Comment: Edited the post to make it more clear that this is a question and not a statement